# Why isn't my javascript array properly registering via ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, arrays

I'm using the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 147; i++)
{
     if (!(array[i].Equals("")))
     {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("Stringarray", array[i]);
     }
     else
     {
         break;
     }
}
```

The code executes properly but then if I try to get it on my JavaScript file I get the error that Stringarray is not defined when I do this assignation

```
    var arlene2 = Stringarray;
```

I'm doing the assignation in the design and script part of the file, I'm not trying to use it on another page, that I could understand that could fail. This function has worked on the past so I'm not sure waht could be causing the array not to register properly, maybe I'm missing something as that's everything I have in my code that's related to the array I want to register, except for the fact of creating it on the variable array that I've checked it's done properly, so it shouldn't be an issue.

I've also set this in code:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="Stringarray"  runat="server"/ >
```

But it doesn't change anything where it's on the code or not.

Comment: hopefully this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerarraydeclaration%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) help you.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to build a single string containing the array elements, e.g:

```
string[] array = new[] {"a", "b", "", "c"};
string arrayAsString =
 "\""
 + string.Join("\", \"", array.Where(s=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray())
 + "\"";
```

This creates a string such as: `"a", "b", "c"`

Then you can call the `RegisterArrayDeclaration()` with that value:

```
ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("Stringarray", arrayAsString);
```